# json map to string failure in java

Tags: java, json

In java I am trying to convert a Map to json string. using code below

```
private void sendResponse(Map<String, String> responseMap) throws IOException
{

    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());   
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseMap);
    ps.println(json.toString());        

}
```

The variable

```
json results in {"empty":false}  the map contains valid keyvalue pairs.
```

The map contains values like this

```
        responseMap.put("response", "ok");
        responseMap.put("versionname", "dummy");
        responseMap.put("versioncode", "dummy");
        responseMap.put("package","dummy"); 
        responseMap.put("deviceid", "unknown");
        responseMap.put("devicename", "dummy"); 
        responseMap.put("synclocation", null);
        responseMap.put("extra", "");
```

The code I am using comes from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

any ideas why its not working 
?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear as to what's broken.  What values are contained in your `responseMap`?

Comment: {response=ok, versionname=dummy, extra=, package=dummy, devicename=dummy, versioncode=dummy, synclocation=null, deviceid=unknown-device-id}

Comment: That looks fine with me (using `org.json.JSONObject`).  Where exactly are you seeing this break down?

Comment: json object when contructed i howver over the var and it shows {"empty":false}  same is sent over the network, in json.toString()

Comment: So let me rephrase: the JSON entity looks fine.  Are you sure that the output stream isn't buffering and sending across only a bit of data?  (Although where it's getting "empty" from is beyond me.)  Have you examined the network traffic to see if that's exactly what it's sending across?

Comment: regardless of network, json.toString() returns {"empty":false} which it should not. I think the library has some issue or I am not using the JSONObject constructor correctly

Comment: I think your library has a problem, then.  I'm using the latest `org.json.JSONObject` [from Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json).  I'm not seeing the same problem that you are.

Comment: Thanks @Makoto the jar from the Maven link you gave works fine. It was issue with the code from where I downloaded earlier..

Answer (score 0):

Map to Json, Json to Map? I use `Gson` lib. There is no problem.

Map to Json String

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("111", "AAAAA");
map.put("222", "BBBBB");
String mapString = gson.toJson(map);
System.out.println(mapString);
```

Output

```
{
  "222": "BBBBB",
  "111": "AAAAA"
}
```

Json String to Map

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String mapString  = "{\"222\": \"BBBBB\",\"111\": \"AAAAA\"}";
Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(mapString, Map.class);
System.out.println(map.get("111"));
```

Output

```
AAAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you doing it the way you are doing it.  I created an example project that shows how to do it with Map<String, Object> rather than Map<String, String> .

https://github.com/djangofan/json-serialization-jackson-example/blob/main/src/test/java/com/example/TestObjectsTest.java

In that example:

```
  ....
  private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
  .....
  @Test
  void testDeserialization() {
    Map<String, Object> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    linkedHashMap.put("foo", "bar");
    linkedHashMap.put("bar", "foo");

    TestObjects.Bar bar = TestObjects.Bar.builder()
        .id(3)
        .description("bar description")
        .stringBoolean("false")
        .nestedMap(linkedHashMap)
        .build();
    TestObjects.Foo foo = TestObjects.Foo.builder()
        .id(1)
        .description("foo description")
        .primitiveBoolean(false)
        .bar(bar)
        .build();

    String serialized = null;
    try {
      serialized = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(foo);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    assertTrue(serialized.contains("foo description"));
    try {
      TestObjects.Foo foo1 = MAPPER.readValue(serialized, TestObjects.Foo.class);
      TestObjects.Bar bar1 = foo1.getBar();

      assertEquals(bar1.id, 3);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

  }
```